# I have a WPF Listview and I want to display duplicated values or not, according to the value of a Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, listview

All I wanted is something like a Linq Distinct available to either show duplicates or not, depending on the state of a Checkbox.

this is the XAML (with all properties like names, and everything regarding to layout removed, to avoid distraction):

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView SelectionMode="Single"/>
</ScrollViewer>
<CheckBox Content="group duplicates" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
```

Each item of my list view is a Label with a Hyperlink as it's content, that opens the Uri set in the NavigateUri Property of the Hyperlink with the default internet browser when clicked.

Some of the links appear more than once when the application is run, wich is relevant because it shows the number of occurencies of those uri. I can't get rid of the duplicates when building the list either, because it is ordered by the time at which each uri occurred, and that is also relevant.

Because it is hard for the human eye to distinguish between each uri because of the fact that they look alike a lot, it would be practical to be able to do two things:

1. annotate in the link the number of times that uri occurs in the listview even when it is showing the duplicates
2. to collapse the duplicates into one link (with the number of occurencies properly annotated)

The result I'm hoping to achieve would be something like this:

(displaying duplicates)

- uri1 (2)
- uri2 (3)
- uri1 (2)
- uri3 (1)
- uri2 (3)
- uri2 (3)

(grouping duplicates)

- uri1 (2)
- uri2 (3)
- uri3 (1)

This is how I populate the listvew in the code behind at the moment (irrelevant portions not shown to avoid distraction)

```
foreach (string uriStr in uriStrCollection)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(uriStr);
    Label lbl = new Label();
    Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink();
    link.Inlines.Add(uriStr);
    link.NavigateUri = uri;
    link.RequestNavigate += link_RequestNavigate;
    lbl.Content = link;
    listView.Items.Add(lbl);
}
```

To store uriStrCollection is not a good solution, because it's large and it would be basically storing the same data twice.

To generate uriStrCollection again is an even worse idea, because the process involves a lot more memory and computation.

I tried to use Linq extension methods on ListView.Items and ListView.Items.SourceCollection, but I can't: Linq methods don't even show on auto-complete, wich is very weird to me, specially because the compile time type of SourceCollection is IEnumerable.

Any ideas?

Comment: use Hashset and not ListView

Comment: I want to be able to display this on the window. Hashset isn't a Control as far as I know. Besides, I want to preserve both the order and the duplicates. I just want to be able to choose between displaying the duplicates or not.

Comment: Exactly a HashSet is not a UI control.  Use a collection for a collection an a UI control for UI.  Could add the items to both a List and HashSet or use linq for distinct from List using GroupBy.

Comment: Hashset is the data collection in order to create a unique set, bind it to the collection you want using itemssource. also yes you can use distinct() in List.

Comment: @Blam Then I would bind the List to the Listview right? But how do I do that? I don't want to take properties of the objects in the list. I want the objects themselves. Is there a binding expression for that?

Comment: @Androidy A unique set is not the solution I need. I specifically mentioned I need to keep both order (something you lose with Hashset) and the duplicated instances (Hashset overwrites duplicates). I know I can use Distinct with List. I was talking about Listview.Items and Listview.Items.SourceCollection. I can't use Distinct (or any Linq extension method) on them.

Comment: Really you don't want a property in the list.  Just what do you expect an object to look like in a list?   There are many examples of binding on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using WPF, let's start by doing this the WPF way - separate the data from the UI; the UI should be used to *display* the data, not *store* it.

Forget the UI for now. First, create the classes and data structures you need to store a list of URIs and their occurrences in code, for example:

```
public class UriWithOccurrence
{
    public string UriString { get; set; }
    public int Occurrences { get; set; }
}

...

//Keep a global collection of URIs:
_allUris = new List<UriWithOccurrence>();

foreach (string uriStr in uriStrCollection)
{
    var item = new UriWithOccurrence()
               {
                   UriString = uriStr,
                   Occurrences = uriStrCollection.Count(s => (s == uriStr))
               };

    _allUris.Add(item);
}
```

Now we start thinking about displaying these URIs in the UI an create a `ListView` that can list `UriWithOccurrence`s. Note the `DisplayMemberBinding`s which point to properties in UriWithOccurrence:

```
<ListView x:Name="_list" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Link" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UriString}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="#" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Occurrences}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

To connect the dots and see some URIs, we set the ListView's `ItemsSource` to our URI collection:

```
_list.ItemsSource = _allUris;
```

This article explains all this more in-depth: http://tech.pro/tutorial/742/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1

*To get clickable URIs, this MSDN question may be helpful: [WPF ListView "hyperlink url" column](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/584a1317-9e2f-4954-8d8c-922fb5ccc3c1/wpf-listview-hyperlink-url-column-wpf-documentation-sucks?forum=wpf)*

Finally, to get the "Group duplicates" checkbox working, a quick and dirty solution could be:

```
private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _list.ItemsSource = _allUris;
}

private void CheckBox_UnChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _list.ItemsSource = _allUris.GroupBy(u => u.UriString)
                                .Select(gr => gr.First());
}
```

**A final tip:**

To *really* do this the WPF way, read up on the **MVVM pattern** and put most of this code in a `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks, that solves it. I was simply trying to avoid the WPF way, I suppose. I was reluctant in creating a new type just for this, and a separate List, hoping I could use the one built in Listview, for example. I like short solutions but I guess this is not always possible and sometimes we have to add more stuff to our code, not only to make it work but also to make it more intelligible to others. Again, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it takes a different mindset. But once your project grows even a little bit, I find that it actually reduces the amount of code needed ..as well as being more intelligible as you point out.